# "Print" specific columns through foreign keys

Tags: postgresql, join, foreign-key

I have three tables:

- `Users`
- `Users_request`
- `Users_applications`

Table `Users` has the `id` column, that column is related on `Users_request.id` finally `Users_request.id` is related with `Users_applications.id`

**I try to do:**

Users table has a column called `name` and User_applications has `application_name`.
I want to "print" only those columns with their rows through JOIN clause.

Desired Output:

```
 user| application_name|
-----|------------------
user1| application1
user2| application2
userN| applicationN
```

I have the next, but I want improve it not using hardcode `Users_applications.id`

```
SELECT Users.id, Users_applications.name 
  FROM Users, Users_applications 
 WHERE Users.id = 'User1' AND User_applications.id = n ;
```

Is there any other way to accomplish it, through only `Users.id` using JOIN clauses?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Table Users has the id column, that column is related on
>   Users_request.id finally Users_request.id is related with
>   Users_applications.id

So Users.id = Users_request.id and Users_request.id = Users_applications.id which means that Users.id = Users_applications.id

Then you can do:

```
SELECT Users.id, Users_applications.name 
FROM Users INNER JOIN Users_applications  ON Users.id = Users_applications.id
WHERE Users.id = 'User1';
```